# Can't add marker with google-maps-react

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-react, react-fullstack

```
import {Map, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react'


var React = require('react')

class GoogleMapContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Map google={this.props.google}
                style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'relative'}}
                className={'map'}
                zoom={14}>
              <Marker
                title={'The marker`s title will appear as a tooltip.'}
                name={'SOMA'}
                position={{lat: 37.778519, lng: -122.405640}} />
              <Marker
                name={'Dolores park'}
                position={{lat: 37.759703, lng: -122.428093}} />
              \\
            </Map>

        )
    }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyDq-nhDEOWaOzLfFAr9Lx4dlvEBIpHMxCk'
})(GoogleMapContainer)
```

i have this code that gives me an error in the browser console

```
ReferenceError: Marker is not defined
```

but in the documentation of the package they never import Marker
https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react

i can't discover what is happening

Comment: It looks like you're missing the Marker import: ```import {Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react'```

Comment: if i do that the error changes to "this.marker is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`import {Map, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react'`

to

`import {Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react'`

Marker is not yet imported

Answer (score 0):

As is said in the comments, `Marker` is not included in the import. The object is not defined because it was never imported. You can not use an object that is not present. Rewrite the top line to say this:

```
import {Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react'
```

Comment: if i do that the error changes to "this.marker is undefined"

Comment: and in the Quickstart in https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react they never import Marker or InfoWindow

Comment: Is Marker imported from google maps as in `import {Marker} from 'google-maps'`

Comment: My other thought is that perhaps google maps is not being loaded at all. I think this might be the case because after a little research I think I have found that Marker does not need to be imported to use them. So, using React it might seem like google maps getting loaded is a given when it is not.